# Image in PDF becomes black box when printed

Tags: macos, big-sur, preview, printing

I opened a PDF in Preview.app.

When I print it, one image on one page is printed as a solid black box.

How can I stop that from happening? I would like it to print exactly as it previews.

Comment: If you print the same PDF from another _application_ that can handle PDF documents, does it print properly? Can you upload a copy of the PDF?

Comment: Try opening the PDF in Firefox